# Migration syntax errors when adding utf-8 and InnoDB instructions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I am trying to create this rails migration

```
class CreateFormats < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table (:formats , :options => 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' ) do |t|
      t.name
      t.description 
      t.company

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :formats
  end
end
```

And I get errors during execution that look like this:

syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
    create_table (:formats , :options => 'ENGINE=InnoDB D...
                            ^
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' ) do |t|
...                               ^

syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

Any idea why this happened?  I can't find any problems with my syntax..most likely because I am new to Rails :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect:

```
create_table (:formats , :options => 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' ) do |t|
```

should be

```
create_table(:formats , :options => 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' ) do |t|
```

i.e: without the space. Otherwise you are simply grouping `:formats` with `:options => ...` as the first argument to the function.

You probably also need to change

```
t.name
t.description 
t.company
```

to something like

```
t.string :name
t.string :description 
t.string :company
```

Comment: the initial errors got fixed, but now I have this one: undefined method `name' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x92cdb94>

Comment: I just added a note about that to my answer, but the remainder of your table definition syntax is a bit off as well.